# breakers on main panel trip after adding a sub panel

Tags: subpanel

I've just added a subpannel 100amp with Gauge 6 wires to the main panel so that the new subpanel will feed a sauna 25amp + a hot tub 30amp. The sauna is already connected with gauge 8 wires 240V, it works fine. The hot tub is not yet connected.

However, shortly after the sauna is connected i notice that several existing breakers on the main panel would jump from time to time, even if the appliances are not running. I am in an area where electricians are rare to find. Please shed some light

---

i believe that they are non-GFCI/AFCI type, just regular type D. The one that often trips after i added the subpanel is the dryer, after resetting, it would stay on for maybe 10 mins before tripping again, regardless if the sauna is running or not.

Comment: Are these "plain old" breakers or are they GFCI/AFCI types?

Comment: Can we get photos of the panel with the cover off?

Comment: DHL, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how we're different from a discussion forum.

Comment: Sounds like a rule of 6 panel. Two large of a load in the lower section. That is if the sub is correctly wired with no shorts.

Comment: Can we get photos of the main panel and the subpanel please?  Also, what size breaker did you use in the main panel to protect the feeder to the subpanel?

Comment: Will be very difficult to figure this out without seeing pix of the panel.